# Flattening a dictionary of dictionaries that contain lists

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, flatten

I have a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
data={'data': 'input',
 'test': 
 {
    'and': 
    {
    'range': {'month': [{'start': 'Jan','end': 'July'}]},
   'Student': {'Name': ['ABC'], 'Class': ['10']}
     }
  }
}
```

I need to flatten this dict into a dataframe.I tried to use json_normalize() to flatten the dictionary and the output I got looked like this:
[image]

My desired output is something like the one given below.

### [image]

This can be done in R by using **as.data.frame(unlist(data))** but I want to do the same flattening in **Python**. I am a novice in python so I dont have much idea about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an attempt to normalize your json object by writing a recursive function as follows:

```
data={'data': 'input',
 'test': 
 {
    'and': 
    {
    'range': {'month': [{'start': 'Jan','end': 'July'}]},
   'Student': {'Name': ['ABC'], 'Class': ['10']}
     }
  }
}
sequence = ""
subDicts = []
def findAllSubDicts(data):
    global subDicts
    global sequence
    for key, value in data.items():
        sequence += key
        #print(sequence)
        if isinstance(value, str):
            subDicts.append([sequence,value])
            sequence = sequence[:sequence.rfind(".")+1]
            #print(sequence)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            tempSequence = sequence[:sequence.rfind(".")+1]
            sequence += "."
            #print(sequence)
            findAllSubDicts(value)
            sequence = tempSequence
        elif isinstance(value, list) and isinstance(value[0], dict):
                sequence += "."
                tempSequence = sequence[:sequence.rfind(".")+1]
                #print(sequence)
                findAllSubDicts(value[0])
                sequence = tempSequence
        elif isinstance(value, list) and len(value)==1:
            tempSequence = sequence[:sequence.rfind(".")+1]
            subDicts.append([sequence,value[0]])
            sequence = tempSequence
    return subDicts



outDict = findAllSubDicts(data)
for i in outDict:
    print(i[0].ljust(40," "), end=" ")
    print(i[1])
```

Printing the results will give you:

```
data                                     input
test.and.range.month.start               Jan
test.and.range.month.end                 July
test.and.Student.Name                    ABC
test.and.Student.Class                   10
```

Notify me if you need any clarification or any modification in my code.